# In Linux, how can I get the filename from the "struct file" structure, while stepping thru the kernel with kgdb?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to view the filename via kgdb, so I cannot call functions and macros to get it programatically.  I need to find it by manually inspecting data structures.

Like if I had a breakpoint here in gdb, how could I look around with gdb and find the filename?

I've tried looking around in `filp.f_path`, `filp.f_inode`, etc.  I cannot see the filename anywhere.

```c
ssize_t do_sync_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
     struct iovec iov = { .iov_base = (void __user *)buf, .iov_len = len };
     struct kiocb kiocb;
     ssize_t ret;

     init_sync_kiocb(&kiocb, filp);
     kiocb.ki_pos = *ppos;
     kiocb.ki_left = len;
     kiocb.ki_nbytes = len;

     ret = filp->f_op->aio_write(&kiocb, &iov, 1, kiocb.ki_pos);
     if (-EIOCBQUEUED == ret)
             ret = wait_on_sync_kiocb(&kiocb);
     *ppos = kiocb.ki_pos;
     return ret;
}
```

Comment: OK Stephan, I know this is a separate question, but I've been trying to figure out how to control the code syntax highlighting or at least code recognition for months and haven't found the answer.  How did you fix it to recognize where my c-code started?

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: When a file is opened, the file system looks up the inode from the directory entry, and then forgets everything but the inode; there is no direct connection. Due to mechanisms like hard links, `unlink`, and `O_TMPFILE`, there can be zero or multiple file names for a `struct file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, the `file` structure is essentially how the kernel "sees" the file. The kernel is not interested in the file name, just the inode of the open file. This means that all of the other information which is important to the user is lost.

---

EDIT: This answer is wrong. You can get the `dentry` using `filp->f_path.dentry`. From there you can get the name of the dentry or the full path using the relevant FS flags.

Comment: I guess an answer like, "it cannot be done," is an answer nonetheless.  Thx

Comment: No, the information is here, in kernel:
 $ readlink /proc/6456/fd/33
 /usr/share/qt4/doc/qch/assistant.qch

Answer (score 35):

You can get the filename from `struct file *filp` with `filp->f_path.dentry->d_iname`.

To get the full path call `dentry_path_raw(filp->f_path.dentry,buf,buflen)`.

Comment: Be careful here - d_iname is only for "short" names. For production code, rather use path.dentry->d_name.name

Answer (score 3):

`filp->f_path.dentry->d_name.name`
This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The path is stored in the file->f_path structure as it's name implies.  Just not in a plain-text form, but parsed into objects that are more useful for kernel operation, namely a chain of `dentry` structures, and the `vfsmount` structure pointing to the root of the current subtree.

You can use the `d_path` function to regenerate a human-readable path name for a struct path like file->f_path.  Note that however this is not a cheap operation and it may slow down your workload significantly.

The above mentioned issues about open but unlinked files, multiple hardlinks and similar are valid for mapping from and inode to a pathname, and open file always has a path associated with it.  If the file has been unlinked `d_path` will prepend a " (deleted)" to the name, and if the filename it has been opened with has been changed to something else using rename since it was opened d_path will not print the original name, but the current name of the entry that was used for opening it.

Comment: `s/plane text/plain text/` unless you work for Boeing or Airbus :)