# How to get the node name or path of the character device in kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I've got **"n"** character device in one kernel driver. One read function referred to read pointer.

```
static struct file_operations fops;
fops.read    = cd_read;
```

Now i need to know which character device referred when **read** called from userspace.

```
static ssize_t cd_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *position)
{

    filep->f_path;
}
```

I tried to get it by **filep->f_path** at least tried to print it but 
f_path refers to struct path in **fs.h**

```
struct file {
    ...
    struct path     f_path;
    ...
}
```

dentry and vfsmount in path in **path.h** refers to 2 undefined struct.

```
struct dentry;
struct vfsmount;

struct path {
    struct vfsmount *mnt;
    struct dentry *dentry;
};
```

and stuck in here. 
So how can i get the node name or path of the character device in kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
filp->f_path.dentry->d_iname
```

works as described in here:

[In Linux, how can I get the filename from the "struct file" structure, while stepping thru the kernel with kgdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885676/in-linux-how-can-i-get-the-filename-from-the-struct-file-structure-while-ste)