# Getting the file path of a write system call

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to write a Kernel Module or a kernel space hook to catch all write system calls and get the location of the file it is going to write to, so that I can redirect that write to make changes on a temporary location instead of that particular file.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, but these are not at all same, although I want to "do" something after hooking system call, my main concern is getting the location of a write system call i.e where the write call will write to.

Comment: Because `write` method accepts `inode` parameter, You may obtain the path from it, see that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614757/3440745.