# Can I get the file name from fd (file descriptor) passed by a syscall in kernel code?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, busybox

I doubt it but in the kernel code, can I get the file name for an `fd`(file descriptor) that was passed by a syscall?
In a situation, I get syscall from user space and in `do_el0_svc(struct pt_regs *regs)` function (arch/arm64/kernel/syscall.c, linux-5.10.0-rc5), I can print the `fd` value which is in x0. But can I know the file name from the fd value?
The syscall list for arm64 is [here](https://thog.github.io/syscalls-table-aarch64/latest.html) with number and function, arguments.

Comment: Why not solving it in a library with LD_PRELOAD? It seems you are just debugging and not using the fd in kernel, right?

Comment: *"I doubt it"* - why? if anyone has this information it's the kernel :') a bit of googling yields this which you may find useful: https://gist.github.com/larytet/f870e2ca5607876e24b529705e9cdb1b

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi How can I use LD_PRELOAD? (I guess by replacing the function using a .so file?) But I forgot to mention that my board doesn't boot to the shell and this problem is arising while starting /bin/sh of busybox..

Comment: @MarcoBonelli that seems nice. I was following from the busybox side but I could try that method. (I'm about to go out on a 4-day long holiday in Korea, so after that.. ) thanks.

Comment: @ChanKim can't use `LD_PRELOAD` in your environment, that's an environment variable used by the dynamic loader, which you do not have as you are working with busybox. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: From the file descriptor you could obtain `struct fd` object using `fdget_pos()` function. Field `file` of that object is a `struct file` representing a file. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885676/in-linux-how-can-i-get-the-filename-from-the-struct-file-structure-while-ste) and its answers describe how to get name of the file from `struct file` object.